# How to hide certain numbers of divs generated from array loop using template literal

Tags: javascript, arrays, template-literals

I'm trying to make an easy way to add projects to my portfolio by adding an object for every project to an array, and the problem is that I want to show only three projects and whenever someone clicks on a button it shows it all

I tried using "break"
also tried to make a boolean variable
didn't work

```js
let arrname = [
 {name: "project one"}, 
  {name: "project two"},
 {name: "project three"},
 {name: "project four"},
 {name: "project five"},
 {name: "project six"}
];

for(let i=0; i < arrname.length; i++){

  let stmain = `
  <div id="main" class="main">
    <div class="img"></div>
    <div class="info">
      <p>${arrname[i].name}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
 `;
  mylist = document.getElementById('test');  
  mylist.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', stmain);
}
```

```css
.main{
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 2rem auto;
  background-color: #2b2b2b;
  color: #ffffff;
 
}
.img{
  width: 100%;
  height: 80%;
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
.info{
  padding-left: 20px;
}
button{
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
<button id="btun">show more/less</button>
```

Comment: so there are only 6 projects in total? if not, how do you want the display when there are 7?

Comment: this is just an example for my portfolio it will be more than that 
and probably will be different from small screen to large 
but it's the same really so say I want to show only the first three then when hitting the button show all of them

Comment: change `i < arrname.length` to `i < 3`

Comment: @zer00ne I'm afraid this won't do much it will be always three and this isn't what i need

Comment: @KhaledMahfoz *"...that I want to show only three projects"*  *".. I want to show only the first three then when hitting the button ..."*

Comment: @zer00ne I also said when someone hit the button all of the divs show up
and when hitting it again it collapses :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

won't be the best script but hopefully this would give you a further more idea on what you need

for js

```
    const projects2show = 3;
    let arrname = [
        { name: "project one" },
        { name: "project two" },
        { name: "project three" },
        { name: "project four" },
        { name: "project five" },
        { name: "project six" },
        { name: "project seven" },
        { name: "project eight" },
    ];

    for (let i = 0; i < arrname.length; i++) {

        let stmain = `
    <div id="${i + 1}" class="main hide">
    <div class="img"></div>
    <div class="info">
        <p>${arrname[i].name}</p>
    </div>
    </div>
`;
        mylist = document.getElementById('test');
        mylist.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', stmain);
    }


    function showProjects() {
        const projects = document.getElementsByClassName('hide');
        for (let i = 0; i < projects2show; i++) {
            if (projects[0]) projects[0].classList.remove('hide');
        }
    }
    showProjects();


    const show = document.getElementById('btun');
    show.addEventListener('click', () => {
        showProjects();
    })
```

for css I just added this

```
.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

basically I am hiding all projects on start then just show the first 3.
When button is clicked, get all the hidden one then show the first three, when clicked again, do the same thing

again, just hoping this would give you some ideas

Comment: first of all, thank you for your time and effort 
and this gave me an idea or two i hope
but i don't want to show 3 divs every time i just want it to show only the first 3
then when hitting button show the rest and when hitting again collapse to the first 3 again..

Comment: @KhaledMahfoz got what you mean, but you also have to think of some user cases as I mentioned earlier what if there are 7 or 8+ projects.  If only showing three then click shows all 8+ another click shows three again.  As a user, I would say it's kind of weird but of course it's doable.  Let me add codes in a bit.

Comment: @KhaledMahfoz What I can think of and giving you an idea is check how many projects are shown when clicked if project shown length is 3 then show the rest, if more than 3 then hide the rest

Comment: I actually considering doing it your way, I think it's gonna be helpful for the UX
so thank you for that and I actually figure it out 
I think it's not best practice cause it's a bit messy but that's all I got 
if you have any suggestion on how to make the code better, I would really appreciate it :')

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out

```js
let arrname = [
 {name: "project one"}, 
  {name: "project two"},
 {name: "project three"},
 {name: "project four"},
 {name: "project five"},
 {name: "project six"}
];

for(let i=0; i < arrname.length; i++){
  
  let stmain = `
  <div id="main" class="main">
    <div class="img"></div>
    <div class="info">
      <p>${arrname[i].name}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
 `;
  mylist = document.getElementById('test');  
  mylist.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', stmain);
}

let bool = false;

function myFunc(){
 for(let x = 3; x < arrname.length; x++){
  if(bool == false){
   document.getElementsByClassName("main")[x].classList.add("hide");
  }else{
   document.getElementsByClassName("main")[x].classList.remove("hide");
  }
 }
}
myFunc();


let btn = document.getElementById("bton");
btn.onclick = function(){
 bool = !bool;
 myFunc();
}
```

```css
.main{
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 2rem auto;
  background-color: #2b2b2b;
  color: #ffffff;
 
}
.img{
  width: 100%;
  height: 80%;
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
.info{
  padding-left: 20px;
}
button{
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
}
.hide{
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
<button id="bton">click me</button>
```

Comment: nice, you should give yourself the answer check :D you solve it ~!~!
just my own preference I would do this but there's nothing wrong with yours.  https://jsfiddle.net/0m4egLup/ using ternary operator for `myFunc()` and using `const` instead of `let` for your `btn` variable

Comment: nice changes definitely going into my code :D 
and I just got the idea from your code so here you go 
thank you so much